# RaspberryPi: TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__ dht22 lcd 16x2

Tags: python, format, lcd

Using DHT22 sensor, display LCD 16x2 and raspberry pi to collect temperature and humidity value.Please help me out with this error.Thanks in advance

```py
import drivers # Imports Custom LCD Display Driver
import socket # Imports socket function
import struct # Imports structure function
import fcntl # Imports networking function
import time # Imports time function
import os # Imports Operating System function
import re # Imports Reg Ex function
from time import sleep # Imports sleep function from time module
import Adafruit_DHT
DHT = 4
disp = drivers.Lcd() # Initializes LCD Display


    def tempcpu(): #Defines "tempcpu"
       for _ in range(5): # Sets up timer

         cputemp = os.popen("vcgencmd measure_temp").readline() 
         
         celsius = re.sub("[^0123456789\.]", "", cputemp) 
         h,t = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, DHT)
         disp.lcd_display_string("CpuRpi: {}C".format(celsius), 1) 
         disp.lcd_display_string("T={0:0.1f}C H={1:0.1f}%".format(t,h), 2 )
         sleep(1) # Sleeps for one second before restarting loop


         
    while True: # Forever loop

        tempcpu() # Calls "tempcpu"
        disp.lcd_clear() # Clears the LCD Display


 except KeyboardInterrupt: # If interrupted by the keyboard ("Control" + "C")

       disp.clear() #clear the lcd display
       sleep(1) #sleeps 1 second
       disp.backlight(0) #Turn Off Backlight

   # Exits the python interpreter
   exit()
```

Error :

> disp.lcd_display_string("T={0:0.1f}C H={1:0.1f}%".format(t,h), 2 )
> type Error:unsupported format string passed to NoneType.**format**

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your error with the following line (or similarly if `t` is the one set to `None`):

```
h = None,
t = 1
str_to_be_printed = "T={0:0.1f}C H={1:0.1f}%".format(t,h)
```

The method `Adafruit_DHT.read_retry` returned `None`. It probably happens when failing to read the sensor values. Maybe there is an error in your circuit, or the sensor is faulty.

More complete example on https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/92777/Adafruit_DHT.read_retry